# Android error “unable to find explicit activity class”

Tags: android

I've been at this for hours and can't figure it out.  When I debug, it gives the above error.  I'm new to this so go gentle if it's something obvious that I"m missing...

here's the code which introduced the crash from the first activity, it's still labeled 'Main':

```
//-- Menu Press --

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

//-- Handle item selection
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent menu = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
            menu.putExtra("plWin", plWin);
            menu.putExtra("plLoss", plLoss);
            menu.putExtra("plDraw", plDraw);
            startActivity(menu);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_reset:
            if (opCounter > plCounter) {
                plLoss++;
            }else if (opCounter < plCounter) {
                plWin++;
            }else {
                plDraw++;
            }
            opCounter = 0;
            plCounter = 0;
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }

}
```

and the second activity, currently named 'Menu':

```
public class Menu extends Activity {

Intent menu = getIntent();
int wins = menu.getIntExtra("plWin", 0);
int losses = menu.getIntExtra("plLoss", 0);
int draws = menu.getIntExtra("plDraw", 0);

private TextView winNum = null;
private TextView lossNum = null;
private TextView drawNum = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


    //-- Win Counter --
    LinearLayout winView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.plLeft);
    winNum = (TextView) winView.findViewById(R.id.winNum);
    winNum.setText("" + wins);

    //-- loss Counter --
    LinearLayout lossView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.plMid);
    lossNum = (TextView) lossView.findViewById(R.id.lossNum);
    lossNum.setText("" + losses);

    //-- Draw Counter --
    LinearLayout drawView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.plRight);
    drawNum = (TextView) drawView.findViewById(R.id.drawNum);
    drawNum.setText("" + draws);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

and here's my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sesto.life.counter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.sesto.life.counter.Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >

    </activity>  

</application>
```

I'm looking for ideas.  Thank you all in advance

Comment: can you post your logcat?  Also in your onBackPress method you should call super.onBackPress before your finish() otherwise it never gets called.

Comment: Please, post the logcat. Anyway, this kind of error is usually thrown because you forgot to declare the activity into the manifest. Did you declared it?

Comment: I want to, but it want let me... too long

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.sesto.life.counter/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
at com.sesto.life.counter.Main.onOptionsItemSelected(Main.java:141)

Comment: at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2502)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:950)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:163)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)

Comment: at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1060)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2516)
at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3170)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)

Comment: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Don't post the log in comments, simply edit it into your main question. That way, everyone can see it, and it will be properly formatted.

Comment: tried but it kept telling me it wasn't properly formatted.  Still learning here :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I only see one possible mistake is at  `Intent menu = new Intent(this, Menu.class);`
 . Please check `Menu.class` is  your `Menu class` but not `Android Menu View` (located at `android.view.Menu`). The logcat told that it can not find `android.view.Menu` in `manifest`. Hover your mouse pointer above `Menu.class` to check which class you imported for this.

Comment: That was it!  I changed the class from Menu to Options and now I'm getting a nullpoint exception, lol.  But at least that's just some added debugging.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.sesto.life.counter.Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >

</activity>
```

to

```
<activity 
    android:name=".Menu"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >

</activity>
```

and see if that helps

Comment: that's how it was originally.  I changed it to that to see if it helps.  it didn't

Answer (score 1):

I got this error message when I forgot to add The Activity in Manifest file.